# How do I add to my int variables when I press a key?

Tags: variables, integer, console.readkey

The title summed up what I am trying to figure out.

I am trying to get my int variables to increase and/or decrease depending on what directional key I press.

```
int x;
int y;
x = 0;
y = 0;

Console.WriteLine("X:" +x + "Y:" +y);

while (Console.Readkey().Key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow)
{
y = +1;
}
```

If I press the Up arrow nothing happens, if I press any other directional keys it will exit the Console. I fell that I am on the right track because of that alone.

Any help is awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go. I've written this in a way that I'm assuming does what you want it to do.

```
int x = 0; 
int y = 0; 

while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("X:" + x + "Y:" + y);
    ConsoleKey key = Console.ReadKey().Key;
    Console.Clear();
    if (key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow)
    {
        y += 1;
    }
    else if (key == ConsoleKey.DownArrow)
    {
        y -= 1;
    }
    else if (key == ConsoleKey.RightArrow)
    {
        x += 1;
    }
    else if (key == ConsoleKey.LeftArrow)
    {
        x -= 1;
    }
}
```

It saves the current key in `ConsoleKey key` and then checks which direction was pressed, and modifies x or y as necessary.

Note that I also added a `Console.Clear()` so everything prints neatly instead of repeatedly one after another.

Comment: I built something of a text-based RPG before using C#. I am just going to go and reuse some of that code. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: So what you have is working, however it'll only repeatedly say 1 instead of adding 1 to the int.

Comment: Actually I got it. Never mind thank you again for all your help.

Comment: Good deal, good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

Brackets `{}` should appear after a while statement, and the k in "Readkey" should be capitalized (e.g. "ReadKey")

```
while (Console.ReadKey().Key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow)
{
    y = +1;
}
```

Edit: There was as semi-colon after the while statement, making the loop null. This version should work.

Comment: Thank you. Still does not seem to be working. Possible mistaken empty statement is something I am getting on the ReadKey line.

Comment: I've edited the answer so it reflects changes that should make it work.

Comment: Still nothing.  I have everything else working expect key presses...

Comment: Sounds like there might be a problem somewhere else in the program then. I tested my version in Visual Studio and each time I pressed the up arrow it would increment y

Comment: I have edited my post to show what else I have written out.